# Substract time-values from same column in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to do substract time-values from the same column. I already orderd the values that need to be substracted from each other. I will add a picture of my table, so you have a general idea. Now I need to substract number 1 from number 2, number 2 from number 3,.... (from same vehicle) And put it in a column named Consumption for example.

As an If function gave me an error i tried to go to a case function. But now I get the error : "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations. Problem code is the CASE-function till @lastvalue = AGVLoggingrunstate.starttime. I apparently can't put this code inside data-retrieval code. So how do I have to do it ?  Do I need to make a stored procedure ? Tips are welcome.

```
Declare @lastSN AS nvarchar, @lastValue int;  
SET @lastSN = 'AGV';
SET @lastValue = 0;

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AgvLoggingRunstate.vehicle,AgvLoggingRunstate.starttime) AS Row,
  AgvLoggingRunstate.id,
  AgvLoggingRunstate.vehicle,
  AgvLoggingRunstate.node,
  AgvLoggingRunstate.runstate,
  AgvLoggingRunstate.orderclass,
  AgvLoggingRunstate.loaded,
  AgvLoggingRunstate.starttime,
  AgvLoggingRunstate.endtime,
  DATEDIFF(second,AgvLoggingRunstate.starttime,AgvLoggingRunstate.endtime) AS DiffDate,
Case 
WHEN @lastSN = AgvLoggingRunstate.vehicle Then AgvLoggingRunstate.starttime - @lastValue 
ELSE 0 
END AS Consumption,

@lastSN = AgvLoggingRunstate.vehicle,
@lastValue = AgvLoggingRunstate.starttime


FROM  AgvLoggingRunstate

Where AgvLoggingRunstate.starttime > @Startdate and   AgvLoggingRunstate.starttime < @Enddate and AgvLoggingRunstate.runstate = 'Battery'

Order by

AgvLoggingRunstate.vehicle,
AgvLoggingRunstate.starttime
```

[image: table]

Result after Answer and adding an `order by` function :

[image]

Now the only incorrect answer is between two days. I need to filter this out. (Still reading all the info over `COALESCE`,`LEFT JOIN`,.. Because answer isn't completely clear yet to me)

```
WITH Times (RowNumber, vehicle, starttime,endtime)
AS
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vehicle, starttime),vehicle, starttime,endtime FROM AgvLoggingRunState WHERE starttime > @Startdate and  starttime < @Enddate and AgvLoggingRunstate.runstate = 'Battery') 

SELECT CurrentTime.Vehicle,
             CurrentTime.StartTime,
             CurrentTime.EndTime, 
             NextTime.StartTime AS NextTime,
             COALESCE(DATEDIFF(SECOND,CurrentTime.StartTime,NextTime.StartTime),0)                      
             AS Seconds,
             COALESCE(DATEDIFF(SECOND,CurrentTime.StartTime,CurrentTime.EndTime),0) 
             AS SecondsDiffEnd
FROM Times CurrentTime
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Times NextTime
  ON CurrentTime.RowNumber +1  = NextTime.RowNumber
  AND CurrentTime.Vehicle = NextTime.Vehicle  

Order by StartTime
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started correctly with the row number function.  However, you're trying to do with a variable what you need to do with a join.  In the example below, you'll see how I can create the CTE with your row number and then use that in the query, joining to the next record (as long as the vehicles match).
You'll need to determine the correct answer for the last record per vehicle. Right now, it's zero (see the Coalesce Function)
This would be really easy in a future version with LEAD. Oh well.

```
WITH Times (RowNumber, Vehicle, StartTime)
AS 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Vehicle, StartTime),
 Vehicle, StartTime, NextTime FROM dbo.AvgLoggingRunState)

SELECT CurrentTime.Vehicle, 
       CurrentTime.StartTime, 
       NextTime.StartTime AS NextTime,
       COALESCE(DATEDIFF(SECOND,CurrentTime.StartTime,NextTime.StartTime),0)                     
          AS SecondsDiffNext,
      COALESCE(DATEDIFF(SECOND,CurrentTime.StartTime,CurrentTime.EndTime),0) 
          AS SecondsDiffEnd
FROM Times CurrentTime
   -- join to the next time - note that I join both on row number and
   -- on vehicles as I don't want to mix vehicles
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Times NextTime
  ON CurrentTime.RowNumber +1  = NextTime.RowNumber
  AND CurrentTime.Vehicle = NextTime.Vehicle
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your help. One more thing. Can i use this code in my other code ? Now i made a new Dataset. I want to prevent making to many datasets.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand your question.  This code can all go in one dataset. You'll have to provide more information about your report.

Comment: For example i want DATEDIFF(second,AgvLoggingRunstate.starttime,AgvLoggingRunstate.endtime) AS DiffDate, to be entered. in this code. Where do i have to enter it in this code ? Now i have two datasets. One with this code and one with the Datediff. Sorry if this is a stupid question, but trying to understand the complete picture a bit.

Comment: If you provide a schema, this will become easier to understand.

Comment: it's important to provide a schema and expected results to get the correct answer.  I'm guessing that you want to compare the current record's start with the current records end.  I've added that in.  We are using the "currenttime" record"

Comment: I just added all the extra info to the question. Can't add pictures or scheme's in a comment. So did it like that. Hope it's clear.

Comment: I added the code into my code. I think it's what you want

Comment: It has to both in the CTe and then in the select

Comment: Ok. Edited my post with the answer. Thanks for the tips. Last thing is deleting false info like between two following days and the 0's. so it doesn't affect my average if I make an average from 3 days for example. But huge step in the right direction.